# Dropdownlist get the selected value in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a bug which my dropdownlist auto reset value to default! Can u help me! Thanks!

In model, i define:

```
public List <int> StatesId { get; set; }
```

In view:

A:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StatesId, new SelectList(Model.States.Where(p=>p.StateTypeId == s1), "StateId", "StateContent"), "Select")<br /><br />
```

B:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StatesId, new SelectList(Model.States.Where(p => p.StateTypeId == s2), "StateId", "StateContent"), "Select")<br /><br />
```

C:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.StatesId, new SelectList(Model.States.Where(p => p.StateTypeId == s3), "StateId", "StateContent"), "Select")<br /><br />
```

After click submit thì the selected value in A is shown, but the value in B, C box, it will be auto reseted to default which is "select", now, i want to after summit, the value in B and C box will show the value which i have choosen! Thanks

Comment: The `DropDownListFor()` method binds to a value type property (e.g. `int`) but your attempting to bind to a collection (i.e. `List<int>`). If you want 3 dropdownlists, then create 3 properties to bind to. If you want a variable number of dropdownlists based on the number of items in the `StatesId` collection, then you need to use a view model and an associated  `EditorTemplate`.

Answer (score 0):

please, create for each control a different property, do not use the same property for all controls. Of course you can use same data source, but what is selected should be different.

Best

Daniel

**EDIT:**

View:

```
@using System.Linq
@model StackOverflowSamples.Models.StatesViewModel

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedStateA, new SelectList(Model.States.Where(p => p.StateTypeId == s1), "SelectedStateA", "StateContent"), "Select")
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedStateB, new SelectList(Model.States.Where(p => p.StateTypeId == s2), "SelectedStateB", "StateContent"), "Select")
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedStateC, new SelectList(Model.States.Where(p => p.StateTypeId == s3), "SelectedStateC", "StateContent"), "Select")
```

Model:

```
public class StatesViewModel
{
    public IList<StatesModel> States { get; set; }
    public int SelectedStateA { get; set; }
    public int SelectedStateB { get; set; }
    public int SelectedStateC { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I know what you advise but, the value which dropdownlist box return, i save them into a list. A,B,C box have the same type. If foreach box, i create a now variable, i think it is not good

Comment: This does not work in MVC. You must have diferent property for each control, otherwise MVC generates for you dom elements with same Id's and names and this is not good. Look into the generated HTML code and you'll see what I mean. Anyways, if you do what I say, does it work or not?

Comment: can you give me an example, please

Comment: ok, thanks. it works, but if there are very many box in my view, how about another way to do, i don't like to create many variable.

Comment: Sorry but this is not about "liking" is about what is correct...that's a good practice and belongs to SOLID (Single Responsability - each property responsible for its behavior)...

Answer (score 0):

You should either use MultiSelect ListBox connected to StateId to allow selecting multiple States,

Otherwise

If only three states are allowed then declare three StatesIds in ViewModel
like

```
StateId1 { get; set; }
StateId2 { get; set; }
StateId3 { get; set; }
```

and have three dropdownlists in the View